# How to show the Style panel in Firebug within the HTML panel?

Tags: firebug

Here's a screenshot of my problem:

[image: My current situation]

How to enable or show the Style side panel along with HTML panel?

[image: What I want to get]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Since Firebug 1.12](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Firebug_1.12_Release_Notes#Miscellaneous) there is an option to minimize the side panels. There's a button at the right side of the panel toolbar ( [image: Display side panels button]), which allows you to toggle the display.

In your case you have turned on the vertical display of the side panels via Firebug menu > *Options* > *Vertical Panels*, which turns the button into a vertical version ( [image: Display vertical side panels button] ).

Click that button and the side panels will be displayed again.

Answer (score -1):

You may want to have a look at the wiki which states the following .

> This menu (css panel) is reachable via the little arrow in the panel tab ( CSSPanelOptionsMenuArrow.png ) or by right-clicking on on the panel tab.

Link to wiki page about the css tab in firebug:
https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/CSS_Panel

Comment: The problem is to display the side panels, not to show the panel options.